# Relating physics to mathematics in Zero Differential Overlap Approximation

Tags: condensed-matter, computational-physics

Let $\Psi$ be a wavefunction describing a quantum $N=2$   body problem.

In Hartree - Fork method, single - electron spatial - orbital can be expressed as a linear combination of basis function:

$$\psi_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{M}c_{im}\chi_{i}.$$

The action of a Hamiltonian on the wavefunction $\Psi$ yields an energy term $E_{1}$ and energy interaction term $E_{2}$ which consist of coloumb energy $[\phi_{i}\phi_{i} | \phi_{j}\phi_{j}]$ and exchange energy $[\phi_{i}\phi_{j}|\phi_{j}\phi_{i}]$.

Since the spatial - orbital $\psi_{i}$ is expressed as a linear combination of basis functions $\chi_{m}$, there is a computational speed up by reducing the number of terms to be summed be $M^{4}$.

Reading up on Zero Differential Overlap Approximation, it appears that this method can provide some computational speed up through the exchange integral $[\phi_{i}\phi_{j}|\phi_{j}\phi_{i}]$.

$$[\phi_{i}\phi_{j}|\phi_{j}\phi_{i}] = \langle \phi_{i}(r_{1})\phi_{j}(r_{2})|\frac{1}{r_{12}}|\phi_{j}(r_{1})\phi_{i}((r_{2})\rangle = \int\int dr_{1}dr_{2}\phi_{i}^{*}\phi_{j}(r_{2})[\frac{1}{r_{12}} \phi_{j}(r_{1})\phi_{i}(r_{2})].$$

I read that

> ZDO ignores integral that contains product of $\chi_{m}^{i}(r_{1})\chi_{n}^{j}(r_{1})$ so that the above reduces to $s_{\mu\nu} = \langle \mu_{A}|\nu_{B}\rangle = \delta_{AB}\delta_{\mu\nu}$

1. For $\mu$, $\nu$ being the being single - electron spatial orbital and $A, B$ being the electrons.
   How should I best build a mental image of $s_{\mu\nu} = \langle \mu_{A}|\nu_{B}\rangle = \delta_{AB}\delta_{\mu\nu}$?
2. Would anyone be kind enough to explain the detailed step from
   $[\phi_{i}\phi_{j}|\phi_{j}\phi_{i}] = \langle \phi_{i}(r_{1})\phi_{j}(r_{2})|\frac{1}{r_{12}}|\phi_{j}(r_{1})\phi_{i}((r_{2})\rangle = \int\int dr_{1}dr_{2}\phi_{i}^{*}\phi_{j}(r_{2})[\frac{1}{r_{12}} \phi_{j}(r_{1})\phi_{i}(r_{2})]$ to $s_{\mu\nu} = \langle \mu_{A}|\nu_{B}\rangle = \delta_{AB}\delta_{\mu\nu}$ so that I may follow it to the conclusion? Perhaps a simplest case of 2 - electrons to provide me with a flavor?